# Convert UTC time to local time while using the local year/month/day and specifying the hours/minutes JAVA

Tags: java, datetime, utc

I'm trying to convert 09:00 UTC into the local equivalent like this:

```
    ZoneId localZoneId = ZoneId.of(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    DateTimeFormatter formatt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").withZone(localZoneId);
    ZonedDateTime test = ZonedDateTime.of( 2020 , 4 , 25 , 9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        String test2 = formatt.format(test);
        System.out.println(test);
        System.out.println(test2);
```

**Output**

```
2020-04-25T09:00Z[UTC]
02:00
```

However, instead of manually entering the the year, month and day I want to grab the current year, month, day from the local machine but still keep the hour/minutes at 09:00.this part of the code needs to work like this

```
    ZonedDateTime test = ZonedDateTime.of( currentYear, currentMonth , currentDay, 9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Was thinking of doing this but it seems like alot of code:

```
        ZonedDateTime dateparse= ZonedDateTime.now();
        ZoneId localZoneId = ZoneId.of(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        DateTimeFormatter formatFullLocal = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").withZone(localZoneId);


        DateTimeFormatter year = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy");
        String localMachineYearString= year.format(dateparse);
        int localMachineYearInt = Integer.parseInt(localMachineYearString);


        DateTimeFormatter month= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M");
        String localMachineMonthString= month.format(dateparse);
        int localMachineMonthInt= Integer.parseInt(localMachineMonthString);


        DateTimeFormatter day= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd");
        String localMachineDayString= day.format(dateparse);
        int localMachineDayInt= Integer.parseInt(localMachineDayString);


        ZonedDateTime test =ZonedDateTime
                .of(localMachineYearInt, localMachineMonthInt , localMachineDayInt , 9 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now().with( LocalTime.of( 9 , 0 ) )
```

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) object, when passed to the [`with`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with(java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster)) method, acts as a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html), to move to a different date-time value. That value is delivered in a fresh new object rather than altering the original, as [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

The line of code above depends implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to specify explicitly.

## Details

By the way, do not mix legacy date-time classes with *java.time* classes. Avoid the legacy classes entirely. So this:

```
ZoneId localZoneId = ZoneId.of(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

…should be:

```
ZoneId localZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Also, “local” in *java.time* means “not zoned”, or the zone/offset is unknown or unspecified. So your variable name `localZoneId` is confusing. Should be something like this:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

---

You said:

> I want to grab the current year, month, day from the local machine

Determining the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

You said:

> but still keep the hour/minutes at 09:00

A `ZonedDateTime` represents a date and a time-of-day, in the context of a time zone. You can specify each of those three parts in the factory method [`ZonedDateTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalTime,java.time.ZoneId)).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 9 , 0 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( today , lt , z ) ;  // Pass date, time, zone.
```

Comment: Amazing, Thank you! Learned alot just from this answer.